# js finding objects last key with minus 1, why?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

to get the last key of an object this is what i must write, but i don't understand why we need minus -1

```
Object.keys(myObject)[Object.keys(myObject).length - 1]
```

I have tried to remove minus 1 and it is undefined in the console.

Comment: Array indicies start at 0.

Comment: `Object.keys()` is an array; in Javascript, arrays are 0-based, so the first element has index 0 and the last element has index array.length - 1.

Comment: oh okay i forgot that, thanks everyone

Comment: Another way to do the same thing: `Object.keys(yourObject).at(-1)`. Although key iteration order is well-defined, normally an object is considered unordered and there is no "last key".

Answer (score -1):

When searching in array, you use **index**. The first item in array has index 0, the next item 1, the next item 2...

However, someArray.length returns **how many items are in array**.

So length starts from 1 (if array isn't empty), but index starts from 0. So you need to deduct 1 :).